# Reorder a master list with multiple sub lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm trying to maintain the order of smaller lists within a larger one. Assume there are three lists:

```
List A = { Beef, Ham, Chicken }
List B = { Cat, Monkey, Dog }

List C = { Veal, Ham, Beef, Chicken, Deer, Dog, Cat, Monkey }
```

Lists A and B are subsets of C. You can see that the items in A are out of order in C. I'd like to maintain the order of A and B inside C. Therefore, the output of C should be:

```
{ Veal, Beef, Ham, Chicken, Deer, Cat, Monkey, Dog }
```

Keep in mind that items that aren't in A or B keep there original location in C (Veal and Deer). And, items in A or B are always together. The ordering of C will have to be done after C is created because A and B orders can change and C will have to be updated if that happens.

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is that syntax you are using? Is it arrays or lists? Does this need to work for exactly three lists, or any number of lists? Is performance an issue?

Comment: What if it's impossible to keep original location of items that are not in A or B? E.g. if C was `{ Ham, Veal, Beef, Chicken, Dog, Cat, Deer, Monkey }` what should become of C after the algorithm completes?

Comment: Tip: Make it easier to answer by providing (pieces of) real code.

Comment: Sorry if I was being unspecific with the pseudo code. It could be any number of lists and they will all be added to a larger final list.

@NikolaAnusev That case is impossible. When A and B are added to C, they will not be split up like that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If that is the case, then I think it makes the most sense for a C to be a list of lists, just as @BrankoDimitrijevic suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
var A = new List<string> { "Beef", "Ham", "Chicken" };
var B = new List<string> { "Cat", "Monkey", "Dog" };
var C = new List<string> { "Veal", "Ham", "Beef", "Chicken", "Deer", "Dog", "Cat", "Monkey" };

// To quickly check if C[i] belongs to the corresponding list.
var sA = new HashSet<string>(A);
var sB = new HashSet<string>(B);
List<string> currentList = null;
int pos = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < C.Count; i++)
{
    string el = C[i];
    if (currentList != null)
    {
        if (pos == currentList.Count)
        {
            pos = 1;
            currentList = null;
        }
        else
        {
            C[i] = currentList[pos];
            pos++;
        }
    }
    else if (sA.Contains(el))
    {
        currentList = A;
        C[i] = currentList[0];
    }
    else if (sB.Contains(el))
    {
        currentList = B;
        C[i] = currentList[0];
    }
}

// Outputs "Veal,Beef,Ham,Chicken,Deer,Cat,Monkey,Dog"
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", C));
```

Answer (score 2):

The C should not be a list, it should be a **list of lists**.

This way, C never has a *separate order* of its own for the sub-list elements, so reordering a sub-list is automatically reflected in C without any extra action. When the time comes, you can easily "flatten" the C using [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

For example:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        var A = new List<string> { "Ham", "Beef", "Chicken" };
        var B = new List<string> { "Cat", "Dog", "Monkey" };
        var C = new List<List<string>> {
            new List<string> { "Veal" },
            A,
            new List<string> { "Deer" },
            B
        };

        Console.WriteLine("ORIGINAL LIST:");
        foreach (var element in C.SelectMany(l => l))
            Console.WriteLine(element);

        // Now reorder one of the sub-lists (swap "Ham" and "Beef"):
        var tmp = A[0];
        A[0] = A[1];
        A[1] = tmp;

        Console.WriteLine("\nREORDERED LIST:");
        foreach (var element in C.SelectMany(l => l))
            Console.WriteLine(element);

    }

}
```

This prints:

```
ORIGINAL LIST:
Veal
Ham
Beef
Chicken
Deer
Cat
Monkey
Dog

REORDERED LIST:
Veal
Beef
Ham
Chicken
Deer
Cat
Monkey
Dog
```

This all works under assumption the sub-lists are disjoint. If some element is shared among multiple sub-lists yet needs to exist only once in C, this model breaks-down. But then again, your original model would break-down as well, so I took a liberty of assuming this is not the case.

Comment: The disjoint assumption is correct. I like your solution, however, Gebb's answer is also correct but he answered first. What is the SO etiquette in this case? I'd like to accept both your answers.

Comment: @morechitlins Once you get enough reputation, you could upvote both ;) Other than that, if you think a new answer is _significantly_ more helpful than the old one, you could unaccept the old one and accept the new one. If you think they are approximately equal, it's OK to use whatever criteria _you_ think is appropriate, including who's first.